# Package signing is enabled but no thumbprint or certificate path is specified

Tags: c#, uwp, visual-studio-2019

I'm getting the following warning:

> Package signing is enabled but no thumbprint or certificate path is
>   specified.

Can someone tell me how to get rid of it?
I don't use any certificates for my project.

Google doesn't give me any good hints on it.

Comment: Please try double click .appxmanifest -> Packaging-> Choose Certificate file -> select from file -> select .pfx file re-assign certificate.

Comment: May I convert this comment as an answer for  this case?

Comment: Also answered here with more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57578299/uwp-no-certificate-found-with-the-supplied-thumbprint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try double click .appxmanifest -> Packaging-> Choose Certificate file -> select from file -> select .pfx file re-assign certificate.